# Uso do fadeIn e fadeOut no click() com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu queria fazer com que ao clicar em um botão, um determinado elemento sumisses com o comando fadeOut(), e ao clicar novamente, ele aparecesse com o fadeIn(). Tentei fazer algo como:

```
    $('nav.mobile h3.shopping-bag').fadeOut();
    if ($('nav.mobile h3.shopping-bag').fadeOut() === true){
         $('nav.mobile h3.shopping-bag').fadeIn();
    } else {
         $('nav.mobile h3.shopping-bag').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Porém, a lógica ou alguma sequência de comando esteja errada. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Ps: Gostaria de algo parecido para trocar e destrocar a cor de um elemento usando a mesma lógica quando eu clicar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ter uma variável de controle pra saber se o elemento está visível ou não. O método [`fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) não te retorna um `boolean` como você espera, ele apenas esconde o elemento.

```js
let estaVisivel = true; // No começo, ele está visível
$("button").click(function() {  // A cada clique, faz um fadeOut ou fadeIn
  if (estaVisivel) {
   $('p').fadeOut();   // Se estiver visível, fadeOut
  } else {
   $('p').fadeIn();    // Senão, fadeIn
  }
  estaVisivel = !estaVisivel; // estaVisivel passará a ter o valor contrário (se era true, será false, se era false, será true)
});
```

```html
<button>Clique</button>
<p>Olá</p>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Ah sim, agora entendi. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Aplicarei a solução.